# ¿Como configuro mi settings.py de mi pagina web en Django para darla de alta en una direccion ip de una computadora?

Tags: python, django

tengo problemas al momento de subir mi pagina web a la direccion ip de mi computadora, es la primera vez que subire un sitio web trabajando con django.

Comment: Buen día, tienes preguntas que han recibido respuesta y no has aceptado, por favor lee la sección [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y procesa las preguntas que has hecho, si tienen respuestas válidas entonces acéptalas, si tienen respuestas que no solucionan tu problema entonces agrega un comentario explicando lo que hace falta

Answer (score 2):

en la parte de alloweh_host  ejemplo  allowed_host ('127.0.0.1', 'localhost','192.168.1.1')

Comment: si, eso ya lo hice pero en si que más tengo que configurar en el settings para poder desplegar mi sitio web?